# Why do we have both “marinate” and “marinade”?

Tags: etymology, suffixes, morphology, derivation

I know *marinade* is the substance and *marinate* is the action, but why do we have both? I can’t think of any other verb-noun pairings that change that consonant.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/marinade) says the verb *marinade* dates back to 1682 and is derived from the French word *mariner*, which was probably connected or inspired from the Italian verb *marinare*.  Interestingly, the first recorded use of *marinade*, as the noun, is from 1725.

Meanwhile the transitive verb, *[marinate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/marinate#h1)* (again Merriam-Webster), is older and dates back to 1645.

> Etymology
> probably from Italian *marinato*, past participle of *marinare* to marinate, from *marino*

Why do we have both forms?
What brings about these different suffixes, and are there other verb-noun pairs that follow that morphology?

Comment: Because sometimes you need a verb and sometimes you need a noun. And if you have both, why not use them?

Comment: I think the question is: why the change in consonant from -ade to -ate?

Comment: alphabet is correct — I’m wondering what informs that change.

Comment: Have you looked up the etymologies of both words? You may be able to answer the question yourself by doing so.

Comment: This is a good question. If you look up the etymologies "marinade came directly from French as is but "marinate" came from French "mariner" which does not have the -t sound at the end that English has. So far I didn't find any source explaining the sound change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does seem strange for the consonant in the suffix to change in that way! I can't think of another *-ate/-ade* pair either.

The explanation might be that the suffixes in "marinade" and "marinate" are unrelated, even though they sound similar. Since the dictionary tells us that "marinade" is a loanword from Spanish via French, let's look at related words in those languages.

"Marinade" is *marinade* in French and *marinada* in Spanish. In both languages, the corresponding verb has an ordinary, regular verb ending (Fr. *mariner*, Sp. *marinar*), a bit like if the English equivalent were "to marine" instead of "to marinate".

(As an aside, if that sounds like something to do with the sea, there's a reason. According to the [Littré dictionary entry for the French verb *mariner*](https://www.littre.org/definition/mariner), its historical meaning was "to cure foods so they don't spoil during a voyage at sea.")

In French, we do find other verb/noun pairs like *mariner/marinade*: *saler/salade* (to salt/a salad), *griller/grillade* (to grill/a barbecue).

In the English verb "marinate", though, we have an "-ate" suffix that doesn't match anything in the French or Spanish verbs. So if it doesn't come from the loanword's original language, where does it come from?

As one of the earlier answerers found, there is an English suffix "-ate" that appears in verbs with Latinate roots such as "macerate" or "concentrate", often scholarly or scientific words. This is unique to English: compare French *macérer, concentrer*. (The [-ate entry in the Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-ate) explains that English speakers of the time derived both adjectives and verbs from Latin adjective forms, in the same way that "warm" is both an adjective and a verb.)

Going back for a moment to the French ending *-ade*, we see it in quite a few culinary terms derived from French, especially names for sauces and similar preparations:

- *anchoïade*, an anchovy sauce; from *anchois*, anchovy
- *persillade*, a fresh herb garnish; from *persil*, parsley
- *chiffonnade*, a knife technique for shredding herbs; from *chiffonner*, to crumple
- *tapenade*, an olive, caper, and anchovy paste; from Provençal *tapeno*, a caper
- *rémoulade*, a mayonnaise-style dressing; from *rémola*, dialect word for a black radish, but spelled as if it were from *rémouler*, grinding knives

We can see from these examples that the suffix *-ade* and its equivalents attach indifferently to nouns, verbs, and adjectives. And aside from the cooking terms listed above, many of the *-ade* words in French appear in a military or other practical context, or derive from regional dialects: *barricade, fusillade, bousculade, charade*... Which is to say that the *-ade* ending doesn't tend to occur in words that historically belonged to a formal or scientific register. It isn't one of the Latinate prefixes and suffixes that already had direct equivalents in English in the early modern period, like "-ation" and "pre-" and many others.

So it isn't surprising that "-ade" as a suffix in English words is almost always seen in loanwords from Romance languages. Looking in the Oxford dictionary, "marmalade" is borrowed from Portuguese *marmelada*, formed from *marmelo*, quince. "Lemonade" is from French *limonade* which itself is probably borrowed from Italian *limonata*, formed from *limone*, lemon.

The noun *marinade*, then, was also borrowed as-is into English, while the verb got same the treatment as more learned Latinate verbs, with the suffix *-ate* getting added to the root *marin-* to form "marinate".

That's how you get "marinade" for the mixture, "marinate" for the action, and from there, "marination" for the process.

Edited to add: as for the question of why "marinate" was coined if "marinade" was already attested as a verb, word borrowings often happen over time as the same idea is translated by multiple people on different occasions, so both forms could very well have appeared independently. I would have expected "marinate" to win out over the verbed-noun form "marinade" over time and "marinade" (v.) still sounds like a more casual usage to me, but it has persisted.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: *marinate* the verb came before *marinade* the verb.

Answer (score 2):

**-ade** produces nouns; **-ate** produces verbs:

According to the OED we have

> **-ade** suffix:
>
> **2. Forming nouns denoting drinks made from the fruit, etc., denoted by the first element, as orangeade n., gingerade n., cherryade n.**

in which I'm willing to see the liquid connection, and

> **-ate**, suffix3
>
> **Origin: A borrowing from Latin. Etymons: Latin -āt-, -āre.**
>
> **A verbal formative, used to English Latin verbs of the first conjugation, and to form English verbs on other Latin words or
> elements. This use originated in the formation of verbs from the
> participial adjectives in -ate mentioned under -ate suffix2.**
>
> Thus nōbilitas gave in Latin nōbilitāre, the English representative of
> which is nobilitate; fēlīcitas, which might have given fēlīcitāre, has
> given French féliciter and English felicitate; and capācitas, which
> might have given Latin capācitāre and French capaciter, has actually
> given English capacitate.
>
> Hence numerous modern verbs, as differentiate, substantiate,
> vaccinate; including many formed on modern or foreign words, as
> adipocerate, assassinate, camphorate, methylate.

Comment: OP's research shows that 'marinade' is also a verb. They ask why two variants exist.

Comment: -ade can signify nouns that aren't beverages or liquids, it can simply denote a general relationship to the root word. I'd say it's more similar to colonnade, renegade, or arcade than to lemonade.

Answer (score 0):

Marinade is the noun that refers to the mixture, marinate is the verb meaning to soak in a liquid marinade.

Something can be marinated because you used a marinade sauce to marinate it.

“Use a spicy marinade to marinate the chicken before cooking it.”

One is the mixture and the other is the process of its use.

You can Marinate something by soaking it in a sauce–you may feel as though you have been marinating in a warm bath–or say a soldier has been marinated in the blood of war.

[ My partner has told me that marinade/marinate is unique because it is a slang not a true morphology. According to him (a chef by profession) marinate is from marination. The etymology originated from Mariners and was originally refered to soaking in brine. ]

Does anyone knows if :ARC: Arcade ( refering to a covered passageway ) & Arcuate ( to bend or form into an arch or curve) is using the same morphology. ??

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is ultimately about the relationship between the suffixes -ade and -ate.

Comment: Marinade is the noun that refers to the mixture,  marinate is the verb meaning to soak in a liquid marinade.  ( i have edited my comnent to make this more clear)

Comment: OP's research shows that 'marinade' is also a verb. They ask _why_ two variants exist.

Answer (score 0):

My partner has told me that marinade/marinate is unique because it is a slang not a true morphology.
According to him (a chef by profession) marinate is from marination.
The etymology originated from Mariners and was originally refered to soaking in brine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello Dezra, welcome to EL&U. May I suggest that you [edit this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/607983/edit)?  Why not group the three answers you posted, in one longer and more complete answer? You can then delete the other two.

Comment: Thank you,  I am very new here. I had a question and thought that I might help answer as well, however I do not have much experience on forum communities.  I appricate your advice.